# Why is my texture stretched?

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: chair showing stretching in UV Checker texture]

[image: chair wire mesh showing seams]

Why is my texture stretched on the front leg? I tried applying scale but no change. I wish I could supply more info but I'm not sure what would help since I'm very new at this.

(update) managed to find doubled vertices along one of the seams which cleared up some stretching. tried to minimise the amount of cuts but still have issues. adding the file, really appreciate if you have a look.

[image]

Comment: well answer is quite simple, your cuts are not 100% right, I cant see your whole mesh, your file would help, or at least your UV map, but what happened that bend are of that place wasn't able to unfold as squares and it stretched itself... do you have bevel on the edges?

Comment: ok. nope no bevel nut i have a sub surf mod.

Comment: top face of that leg is part of the leg or cut with seam?

Comment: It would help to see at least a screen shot of your UV editor window with everything in the chair selected in the edit window.  Better would be if you could include your blend file: ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: managed to find doubled vertices along one of the seams which cleared up some stretching. tried to minimise the amount of cuts but still have issues. adding the file, really appreciate if you have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some distortions are caused by the Subdivision modifier. We can see this if we disable the **Display modifier in edit mode** option.

[image]

In the **Subdivision Modifier** menu it helps if you change the **UV Smooth** type from **Keep Boundaries** to **Keep Corners**.

[image]

You may also find that now if you **UV** > **Unwrap** the "leg" object again you will get better results if you change the **Unwrap** **Method** from **Angle** to **Conformal**.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! thanks!! still got some stretching on the top of the leg close to back. But i think i can fix that with an extra edge loop

Comment: I have edited my answer to suggest that you also try now re-unwrapping the leg and this time change the unwrap method to Conformal.